# Getting raw data using php://input not working

Tags: php

I am having a strange problem and could not figure out how to solve it.I am using webservice from my mobile application to authenticate login details and for that application sends a `$_POST` data to my api and api returns the data.

Now same code seems to work fine through my mobile but if i test it in postman it doesnt work and my `file_get_contents ( "php://input" )` do not return any data.

here is the chunk of code which is not working on my `localhost` and on server,but the same code works fine on my application. If i request through application than it authenticates the data and let the user log in.

```
public function getPostdata() {
    $post = file_get_contents ( "php://input" );
    $data = CJSON::decode ( $post, true );
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested without the decode, just dump the contents of `php://input`?

Comment: @Devon i do not get any data in `$post`,i tried using debugger but `file_get_contents ( "php://input" )` returns `null`.

Comment: Can you please check is any other place where php://input read is used. You can read from this stream only one time. After that it will return only empty. So to check is it works or not(any system issues) - please try to put  file_get_contents ( "php://input" ) as first code line in your code

Comment: @Rinat Yes i have checked that and its the first line of the code.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I know it's 2 years later, but I ran into this today while testing with Postman and it was making me crazy. The problem? I didn't have the end slash on the endpoint URL and so a 301 redirect occurred and cleared out `php://input`.

-.-